# Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenu'

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to publish a MVC web application to a SharePoint 2013 foundation site through Visual Studio 2012. After VS publishes the application the web application displays

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenu'.

```
Line 7:          <!-- Adapter -->
Line 8:          <controlAdapters>
Line 9:              <adapter controlType="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenu"
Line 10:                      adapterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ListMenuAdapter" />
Line 11:             <adapter controlType="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=some#" 

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_Browsers\compat.browser    Line: 9
```